# Connecting to MySQL database from Analysis Services

Tags: mysql, ssas

I need to know whether it is possible or not to get data from a MySQL database and create a Cube in Analysis Services 2008. If so, tell me how to connect to MySQL Database from Analysis Services.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [MyODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc.html). [Install](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-windows.html) the connector, then just set up a [DSN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html) and use it as normal.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a `linked server` connection to the MySQL DB using ODBC. `Openquery` can be used to query the MySQL DB from within SSMS. See these links for [Openquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276848%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), [SQL2008-MySQL linked server](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-linked-server-on-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to get it working. I've used MySQL proxy: http://www.blrf.net/blog/252/microsoft/using-mysql-with-microsoft-analysis-services-for-olap/

Small recap of what I did:

- Get MySQL Connector/NET and make sure you configure the **Sql Server Mode** to true.
- Because SSAS will use COUNT_BIG when processing Aggregation Designs, which MySQL does not understand, I've install MySQL proxy and used this rather simple LUA script to change all COUNT_BIG into COUNT:

function read_query(packet)
    if packet:byte() == proxy.COM_QUERY then

```
    -- try to match the string up to the first non-alphanum
    local f_s, f_e, command = string.find(packet, "^%s*(%w+)", 2)
    local option

    if f_e then
        -- if that match, take the next sub-string as option
        f_s, f_e, option = string.find(packet, "^%s+(%w+)", f_e + 1)
    end

    if string.lower(command) == "select" then
        local query = packet:sub(2)
        if (string.match(query, "COUNT_BIG")) then
            query = string.gsub(query, "%c", " ");
            query = string.gsub(query,"COUNT_BIG%s*%(%s*([^%)]+)", 'COUNT(%1')
            proxy.queries:append(1, string.char(proxy.COM_QUERY) .. query )
            return proxy.PROXY_SEND_QUERY
        end
    end
end
```

end

- You have to point the SSAS to the MySQL proxy.
- Everything else works like a charm for me.